# emacs magit diff highlighting

Tags: emacs, diff, magit

I'm just getting started with magit. 
I really like it, except that the diff viewer is really annoying to me. The chunk highlighting makes no sense because as I scroll around the cursor moves with the screen, highlighting new regions. There is also no other syntax highlighting in the magit diff mode. Does anybody know how to disable the chunk highlighting and get better diff colours other than white on gray?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be a customize group magit which allows you to customize all the different faces for the diff viewer.

In other words, you can run

```
M-x customize-group RET magit-faces RET
```

to see a list of all the faces used by Magit. The ones relevant to the diff viewer are, of course, the ones starting with `Magit Diff`.

Simply customize away and select `Apply and Save`. Alternatively, you can just use the Customize interface to see what faces are available, and then set them directly using `set-face-foreground`, `set-face-background`, and so on in your init-file.

Comment: Some details here would be nice

Answer (score 13):

This is an issue with Magit in combination with Emacs standard theme "wombat".

To work around this, do

```
M-x customize
```

Search for `magit-item-highlight`, click `Show All Attributes`, uncheck `Inherit`, then `Save and Apply` (or maybe only apply).

You lose the highlighting of the current hunk of the diff, but you can tell that still from the hunk's heading anyway, so it was somewhat redundant. Otherwise it resolves the issue nicely.

Comment: This way I also lose highlighting in places where it seems to be useful, for example in logs...

Comment: Very useful description on how to customize. Helped me as emacs newbie.

Answer (score 6):

The zone highlighted correspond to the stash that would be staged when you hit "s".

Inside the hunk, the diff should be colored. You could test the development version (see https://github.com/magit/magit), and if this doesn't solve your issue, add comment in https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/133 about your configuration and exact problem.

Comment: Didn't know it was supposed to be on by default. Did some digging, and turns out my emacs color theme was getting in the way. Disabled it and it's a bit better. The gray highlighting still washes out the text, but I can deal with that, and probably fix it eventually.

Answer (score 3):

If you're running the latest 1.0 version, you can also navigate to any of the diff chunks, hit the 'e' key to get an ediff presentation of the differences.

Comment: I am running version 1.0. hitting e in the status buffer either says "cannot resolv a hunk" or "cannot resolve <filename>"

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to try `M-x customize` for some reason, simply place the following snippet in your `init.el`

```
(defun disable-magit-highlight-in-buffer () 
  (face-remap-add-relative 'magit-item-highlight '()))

(add-hook 'magit-status-mode-hook 'disable-magit-highlight-in-buffer)
```

Source: https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/133